# Boundary of the domain of a polynomial function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ and let :

$A=all(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)≥0$

$B=all(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=0$

Is it always true that B is exactly the boundary of A?

My approach : I believe it is, since $f^{-1}(B)$ contains x,y that are only equal to $0$ whereas $f^{-1}(A)$ contain x,y that are equal to $0$ or greater than $0$.

But answer sheet says that it is wrong. 
Hint is given as the following :

"Construct a polynomial of the form $f(x,y)=(A[x,y])^2B[x,y]$ and examine where $A[x,y]=0$" I couldn't understand what is meant here, Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f(x,y)=x \cdot (x+y)^2$.

Comment: Got it thanks! s